# Inner-object possibilities

Tags: object-motions

What are the possible uses of the `inner-something` command in vim? For example, the following three items work:

- `ci)` in `("hello")`
- `ci'` in `'hello'`
- `ci]` in `([var])`

But the following two do not:

- `ci#` in `# TODO #`
- `ci"` in:

```
"""
This is a python docstring.
"""
```

What are the various limitations then or possibilities in using the `i` (as in "inner") command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the text-objects are documented under `:help text-objects`.

Excerpted from `:help objects`:

```
|v_iquote|  i"         double quoted string without the quotes
|v_i'|      i'         single quoted string without the quotes
|v_i(|      i(         same as ib
|v_i)|      i)         same as ib
|v_i<|      i<         "inner <>" from '<' to the matching '>'
|v_i>|      i>         same as i<
|v_iB|      iB         "inner Block" from "[{" and "]}"
|v_iW|      iW         "inner WORD"
|v_i[|      i[         "inner []" from '[' to the matching ']'
|v_i]|      i]         same as i[
|v_i`|      i`         string in backticks without the backticks
|v_ib|      ib         "inner block" from "[(" to "])"
|v_ip|      ip         "inner paragraph"
|v_is|      is         "inner sentence"
|v_it|      it         "inner tag block"
|v_iw|      iw         "inner word"
|v_i{|      i{         same as iB
|v_i}|      i}         same as iB
```

Comment: These are the ones built-in to Vim, but you can typically extend that list with mappings and you'll find plug-ins that do that. For example, [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim). You'll also find plug-ins that help you define your own, such as [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user). And text objects for specific languages, such as [vim-textobj-python](https://github.com/bps/vim-textobj-python) for Python functions or classes, or [vim-pythonsense](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense) which also has one for Python docstrings.